# How do I pass a struct to a backgroundworker thread in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, arguments, backgroundworker

```
struct ArgumentList {
        int x;
        string text1;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////

ArgumentList arg1={12,"text123"}
WorkerThread->RunWorkerAsync(arg1);
```

I want to passed arg1 but the compiler says "error C2664: 'void System::ComponentModel::BackgroundWorker::RunWorkerAsync(System::Object ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ArgumentList' to 'System::Object ^' "

```
System::Void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {
    //Do stuff with e->Argument
    ArgumentList passedarg=(ArgumentList)e->argument; //'type cast' : cannot convert from 'System::Object ^' to 'ArgumentList'
    int y=passedarg.x
    string text2=passedarg.text1
    //...

        }
```

Comment: Is that `std::string`?  You're going to jump through some hoops in order to make that play well with `BackgroundWorker`, consider using `System::String^` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to declare your struct as a [managed struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w96b5h7.aspx) by using the keyword **ref**

```
ref struct ArgumentList {
        int x;
        string text1;
};
```

That way it will correctly be inherited from the Object type ( the base object for all managd classes ) that [RunWorkerAsync(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f00zz5b2.aspx) expects

Comment: That's not what most .NET programmers would consider a "managed struct".  That would be "value struct" or "value class".  In this instance, though, a reference type is probably better.